# How to use format for list of strings in terraform 0.12.20?

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds

I'm creating data resource to create a policy document for allowing users to access rds, but i'm stuck on how to use format to pass account_id and rds's resource_id,

Code:

```
   data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_authentication_doc" {
      depends_on = [aws_db_instance.name]
      statement {
        effect = "Allow"
        actions = [
          "rds-db:connect"
        ]
        resources = flatten([format("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:${var.account_id}:dbuser:${aws_db_instance.name.resource_id}/%s", var.usernames)])
      }
}
```

Error:

```
resources = flatten([format("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:${var.account_id}:dbuser:${aws_db_instance.pgauth.resource_id}/%s", var.usernames)])
    |----------------
    | aws_db_instance.pgauth.resource_id is "db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    | var.account_id is 8.12345678901+11
    | var.usernames is list of string with 12 elements

Call to function "format" failed: unsupported value for "%s" at 75: string
required.
```

I tried passing

`[formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/%s", var.account_id, aws_db_instance.pgauth.resource_id, var.amp_usernames)]`

got an error

```
  22:     resources = [formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/%s", var.account_id, aws_db_instance.name.resource_id, var.usernames)]
    |----------------
    | aws_db_instance.name.resource_id is "db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    | var.account_id is "123456789012"
    | var.usernames is list of string with 12 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.
```

I want resources like

```
arn:aws:rds-db:us-east1:1234567890:dbuser:db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/foo, 
arn:aws:rds-db:us-east1:1234567890:dbuser:db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/bar, 
arn:aws:rds-db:us-east1:1234567890:dbuser:db-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example with `format` did not work because `format` expects all of its arguments to be single values and it produces a single value.

As you've seen, the `formatlist` function is one way to solve your problem: it produces a list as its result, and if any of its arguments are lists then it repeats the formatting process once for each set of elements with the same index across the lists.

Your second example didn't work because you wrapped the call to `formatlist` in `[ ... ]`, which constructs a list. Becuse `formatlist` returns a list itself, the result was therefore a list of lists of strings rather than just a list of strings.

We can get it working by removing the redundant brackets:

```
  resources = formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/%s", var.account_id, aws_db_instance.name.resource_id, var.usernames)
```

Another way to write this is using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions), which will perhap make the repetition more explicit in your configuration:

```
  resources = [for u in var.usernames : "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:${var.account_id}:dbuser:${aws_db_instance.name.resource_id}/${u}"]
```

Which one is easier to understand is of course subjective: the `formatlist` approach shows the format string up front but it leaves it implied that we're repeating based on elements of `var.usernames`. The `for` expression approach pushes the template to the end of the line, but it makes the repetition based on `var.usernames` more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources = flatten(formatlist("arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:%s:dbuser:%s/%s", var.account_id, aws_db_instance.pgauth.resource_id, var.usernames))
```

i did not specify the type for account_id.